# Partition Table on top of folders containing sub-folders which contains json files in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, data-partitioning

I am working on spark in Databricks. I have a mount point for my storage location pointing to my directory. Let's call the directory as "/mnt/abc1/abc2" - path.
In this "abc2" directory, lets say I have 10 folders named as "xyz1" .. "xyz10". All these "xyz%" folders contain json files, lets call them "xyz1_1.json", so on.
I need to build a table such that I can access my json into spark table by referring it as path + "abc2.xyz1.xyz1_1.json"

```
var path = "/mnt/abc1/"
var data = spark.read.json(path)
```

This works when the json files are directly underlying inside the path and not inside the folders in our path.
I want to figure out a way to which can automatically detect the underlying folders and the sub-folders containing the jsons, and build the table on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With spark 3+ you may add the option [`recursiveFileLookup`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html) as true to search sub directories

```scala
var path = "/mnt/abc1/"
var data = spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup","true").json(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path, RemoteIterator}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

case class Hdfs(fs: FileSystem) {
  implicit def convertToScalaIterator[T](remoteIterator: RemoteIterator[T]): Iterator[T] = {
    case class wrapper(remoteIterator: RemoteIterator[T]) extends Iterator[T] {
      override def hasNext: Boolean = remoteIterator.hasNext
      override def next(): T = remoteIterator.next()
    }
    wrapper(remoteIterator)
  }
  def listFiles(path: String): List[String] = {
    Try(
      fs
        .listFiles(new Path(path), true)
        .toList
        .map(_.getPath)
        .filter(!_.toString.contains("_spark_metadata"))
        .map(_.toString)
    ) match {
      case Success(files) => files
      case Failure(ex) => Nil
    }
  }
}
```

Get hdfs object using spark session.

```
val hdfs = Hdfs(FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration))
```

Get list of files recursively using `listFiles` function.

```
val files = hdfs.listFiles("/mnt/abc1/")
```

Check if files are available or not in hdfs path.

```
if(!files.isEmpty) val data = spark.read.json(files:_*)
```